# cancel update of a string property which is two way boung on error condition

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a textblock which is two way bound to a property called selectedName. this selectedName is also bound to the title text of the page also. when ever I put an empty string in the textblock the title gets updated with the empty string. How do I stop it? I don't want to put conditions in the setter on the selectedName property. which will be the best approach? this is a windows store app

Comment: Why you don't want to put condition in setter ? It is not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Bind the Property as OneWay, the changed value won't be reflected in your Title.